# Как правильно рассчитать масив для Списка

Tags: javascript, java, android, c#, c++

Есть массив из 50 элементов. Данный массив взят для примера, оно может содержать разное значение. 73 элемнта, 92. 242. 841. Точного кол-во элементов не известно.

Есть ListView размер списка регулируется от кол-во элементов массива. /10. Если массив 50. То в ListView списков 50/10=5.

Как сделать так чтобы Каждые 10 элементов отображались в списке?

Тобишь получается ListView из 10 элементов. В Первом элементе. mas[0]-mas[9]
Во втором 10-19.
В третьем 20-29 и т.д.

---

Для Евгения.

Есть число 100. 
Нужно пройтись по всем числам и на каждой десятке сделать паузу.

Comment: посмотрите lodash, функция _.chank

Comment: Не совсем понятно(совсем не понятно) чего именно вы ходите добиться. Вы хотите сделать лист с раскрывающимися вкладками или айтемы по 10 элементов в айтеме?

Comment: @EugeneTroyanskii, Выше обновил для вас

Comment: @xFloooo, спс, но мне надо без сторонних библиотек. Нужен сам алгоритм используя лишь натив

Comment: @AndroLord вам нужно что-то типа пагинации(порционная подгрузка элементов)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = [];

// Для примера 46 элементов в массиве
for (var i=0;i<46;i++){
    arr.push(i)
}

// разбиваем массив по 10 элементов
var chanks = array_chunk(arr, 10);
console.log(chanks)

function array_chunk( input, size ) {
    for(var x, i = 0, c = -1, l = input.length, n = []; i < l; i++){
        (x = i % size) ? n[c][x] = input[i] : n[++c] = [input[i]];
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Жаль что ниче не ясно)).

Особенно сама функция array_chunk.((